# NetBeans does not save a file when it contains an accented word

Tags: netbeans

This is a strange problem. I am programming a Struts2 application. When editing a xml file and add an accented word, NetBeans (in Windows 7) does not save it. When I replace that accented word with the non-accented one, it works.

Anyone knows why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might need some clarification on some of the particulars.  Is this a file.xml file, or a file.config or some such file?  Also, is this xml file part of the project?  If I remember correctly, files can have separate encodings in the NetBeans IDE based on their file extension, though I'm not up on that topic.

That aside though, first off, I would check the file encoding for the xml file and make sure that the encoding it has supports the UTF-8 or UTF-16 character sets.  You can just open it with Notepad and select menu `File -> Save As` to see what the current encoding is, though Notepad++ will give you more information.  If Notepad shows ANSI, then that is probably the issue.  Make a copy of the file with Save As and select UTF-8 as the encoding.  Then see if you can save the file with the characters you want to use and still see them in both Notepad and NetBeans.

I believe the project itself should use an encoding that supports the characters you want to use.  To check that, right click the project and select `Properties -> Sources` and then check the encoding from there.  If it is using any of the Cp125x encoding, switch the project to UTF-8 (if UTF-8 supports the characters you want to use) and then try to save the file with the characters you want again and see what happens.

You should also check the default encoding that the IDE is currently using `NetBeans IDE menu: Help -> About`
If it lists Cp125x, then you may want to switch that to one that will make editing and creating new projects easier: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding

Either way, good luck, I hope one or all of these helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used Notepad++ and I've found the file is in ANSI encoding. However, I compared that file with xx.properties file which contains texts with accented words without problems. But I have realized that, for example, the á is written as \u00e1 when seen in Notepad++ and encoding is also ANSI for that file. Finally, after testing everything, I have replaced the á by &#225; and it worked!. It is annoying, but it was the solution, or patch maybe. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, you're welcome!  As I said in my answer above though, if you want to avoid having to use the decimal or hex escaped values in the file, you can save the file with the UTF-8 encoding, and then upon reopening you'll see the á in the text of the file, which in most cases is easier for readability.  If this answers your original question, please feel free to mark my answer as a solution : )

Comment: The problem was not the encoding, but the file type. However, I tried by saving the file as UTF-8 without success, the same happened. And as I have told you, the file .properties is in ANSI encoding and it shows correctly accented vowels, that is a proof that encoding is not the problem. Maybe this is a bug of Netbeans when dealing with XML files? Regards.

Comment: NetBeans added a feature to the properties file viewer in the past that does a translation of the unicode escaped values (\uxxxx) so that you can see how it will look when used.  That's the only reason you can view the ANSI encoded \u00e1 as an accented character from within NetBeans.  For xml files, NetBeans will use whatever file encoding is defined in the file itself (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>), so maybe you could try setting that value and see what it gets you.  Either way, I think you would really benefit from reading this page: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqI18nProjectEncoding